# Retrieve more than twenty tweets from twitter?

Tags: php, twitter

I would like to know how to retrieve more than twenty tweets from twiiter.
I have looked at the twitter documentation but havent been able to figure out how to do it.
I have code that gets twenty tweets but cant figure out how to get more.
Heres the code

```
$xmldata = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/SkySportsNews.xml';
$open = fopen($xmldata, 'r');
$content = stream_get_contents($open);
fclose($open);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
$i = 0;
while($i < 20)
{
 echo $i . $xml->status[$i]->text . "</br>";  
  $i++;
 }
```

Any help is appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default number of tweets returned is `20`, to change that specify a `count` query string parameter:

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/SkySportsNews.xml?count=200
```

It cannot exceed **200**.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline

---

[EXAMPLE](http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/SkySportsNews.xml?count=200)

Comment: If you need more than 200, Twitter paginates results so you can fetch another 200.